# Can I run different size lights on the same wire?

Tags: electrical

I want to make a lamp out of a glass bottle, but I want to put Christmas lights inside the bottle. I am trying to figure out a way to only have one plug. I want to use a general 60 watt light bulb and generic Christmas lights. Is there a way that I can run them off the same wire so I only have one plug given that they have different gauge wires?

Comment: ooh, ancient technology.  there probably is a way.

Comment: Remember old incandescents make a lot of heat and require their bulbs to be changed frequently.  That will be most problematic with Christmas tree lights, because everytime one burns out, it raises voltage for the rest which dramatically reduces their half-life, causing a race condition.  LED Christmas lights are a much better choice. So is an LED bulb if you can keep it cool (they dislike heat).

Answer (score 1):

If your Christmas lamps are 120v just a lower wattage you can if the lamps are 1-3 volt like miniature Lights usually are you will have to string enough of them in series to add up to 120v but then if one of the many go out they all go out.
Answer based on old school incandescent lamps.

Comment: Can't upvote because "old school incandescent lamps" - not illegal, or at least *shouldn't* be IMHO, but just because they are waste of energy=$ and for safety (heat) inside a bottle.

Comment: @manassehkatz that is what the op specified so that’s how I answered it.

Comment: True. But I have to wonder if "general 60 watt light bulb" was don't-understand-this-watt-thing-consumer-marketing-speak, a.k.a., 60W "equivalent". We'll probably never know.